# Maven works only if run as sudo

Tags: java, maven

I've been recently trying to set-up a java-env on an Ubuntu machine. My current problem is that maven won't pick up the `JAVA_HOME` as executable, and consequently fails:

```
$ JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64"
$ mvn -v
/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-oracle/bin/java
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

If I run `mvn` as sudo, the Java is found normally:

```
$ sudo mvn -v
/usr/bin/java
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 17.0.1, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.13.0-30-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

I would prefer not to use the privileges, as it can cause down-stream problems. I was wondering whether this is a known issue that can be solved?

Thanks

Comment: Check if "$JAVA_HOME/bin" is in your `echo $PATH` and try running `java -version` without root

Comment: `java --version` works fine, `/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin` is present if `echo $PATH`

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by having a custom installation of maven, linked to Jenv. If you are doing this, be careful to:

1. have matching Java versions (double check this)
2. No JDK collisions
3. permissions ok
4. MVN recognizes JDK/bin/java as executable

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else finds this looking for a solution, check your home directory for a .mavenrc file with it's own JAVA_HOME definition.

That's what I found with similar symptoms: [Maven insists JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly, unless I run it as sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73986675/maven-insists-java-home-is-not-defined-correctly-unless-i-run-it-as-sudo/)